# Applying the same CSS attribute to multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a series of elements (over 20) that all need a color that the user enters. Using PHP + CSS I end up with this output:

```
#one, #two, #three, #four, #five, #etc { color: #222; }
```

It works fine, but I now need to edit that color after the DOM has loaded using jQuery/Javascript. Again, it will be user entry so the color could be anything.

Is there a quick way to apply the changes to all the elements at once? Or do I have to do the following?

```
$('#one').css('color', newColor );
$('#two').css('color', newColor );
.... etc
```

I am hoping there is a way, because like I mentioned, there are over 20 elements that need this change.
Thanks guys

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do:

```
$('#one, #two, #three, #four, #five, #etc').css('color', newColor );
```

But if you have a common class assigned to them, it makes it more easier.

```
$('.commonCls').css('color', newColor );
```

Or if these elements are say `div` (and are the only elements) and inside a container `container` then you could just do.

```
 $('.container').find('div').css('color', newColor);
```

and better if you know the color in advance, just add a cssrule for a classname and add that class to these elements, which will help more in cascading than specifying inline color (which `css()` does).

```
$('.commonCls').addClass(newClass);
```

to add on, if you have to use id and if your ids have a common part to it. ex: `#one-Section, #two-Section etc..` then you can use attribute endswith selector ($), You have contains (*) and startswith (^) selector as well.

```
$('[id$="Section"]').addClass(newClass); //or .css
```

Comment: One last question, is there a way to combine elements and a var? So $(somevar, '#one').css....?

Comment: @user2413333 yes, what is somevar? is it a part of the id or some other id? then `$(somevar + ", #one").css`

Comment: somevar is just an example for a cached element in a var, so var somevar = $('#element');

Answer (score 0):

You can use class selector.

```
$('.myclass').css('color', newColor );

or

$('#one, #two, #three, #four, #five, #etc').css('color', newColor );
```